# Using terminal and the open command I am trying to open a new browser instance followed by 2 tabs

Tags: terminal, script, web-browser

I can open a new single instance using `open -na "Firefox" --args --new-window "https://website.com"` however I can't seem to get my script to open a second tab populated with a second url address after that. It only opens with the first site and a blank tab

Answer (score 1):

Set an alias to the executable inside Firefox.app.

```
alias firefox_cli=/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
firefox_cli --new-tab "site1"
firefox_cli --new-tab "site2"
```

For more help, run

```
firefox_cli --help
```

To remove alias,

```
unalias firefox_cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Hope this is found useful

```
open -na "Firefox" --args --new-window "https://website1.com";
sleep 3
open "https://website2.com";
```

The sleep allows for a pause in between the 2 commands and seems to work. Please add a better solution if you know one.