# How can I force an application on MacOS to not use the GPU

Tags: terminal, mac, gpu

Being new to Mac and experienced with Windows, I'm running macOS Catalina (10.15.4) and I have an external GPU for my A.I. and data science training.  However, one of the applications I use (Azure Storage Explorer) seems to have an issue with the GPU, as I can read this in their [release notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-relnotes):

> The Electron shell used by Storage Explorer has trouble with some GPU (graphics processing unit) hardware acceleration. If Storage Explorer is displaying a blank (empty) main window, you can try launching Storage Explorer from the command line and disabling GPU acceleration by adding the `--disable-gpu switch`

My questions:

- Is there an option to mark an application so that it just does not use the GPU by default?
- If not, is there a way to add that `--disable-gpu` automatically to the application, so that I don't have to add it every time ?
- If none of the above work: how can I even start the application (which is installed in the Applications folder) from the terminal?

**Edited**:

- I have found the answer to the 3rd question, but obviously still hope to get a solution by finding an answer to Q1: `do shell script "open -a '/Applications/AzureStorageExplorer.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer' --args --disable-gpu"`

Comment: best is to use alias there.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393142/using-terminal-and-the-open-command-i-am-trying-to-open-a-new-browser-instance-f/393163#393163

Comment: I don't know the answer, but regarding your workaround... You could customize how you launch the app. If it's an application that you want to keep in the Dock or launch on startup, you could use the `Automator.app` or also in this case you could use the `Script Editor.app` to create a custom application that runs the script you posted. You can throw this application into the startup applications or keep it in the dock or maybe launch it using Spotlight.